# Extract a polygonal area from TIFF Image

Tags: gdal, polygon, geotiff-tiff, kmz

I have a TIFF image (actually a satellite image) which is consisting of 5 channels (R G B IR NIR) for a specific region and I have a KMZ file which defines a polygon within that specific region.

I want to extract/map that area from TIFF file and want to read channels pixel-by-pixel.

For example imagine that satellite image encapsulates the Germany and KMZ file has the coordinate information of Munich. What I have been trying is to mask/or cut the region defined by KMZ and then be able to read channels separately only for specified region (Munich).

I have read on a library called GDAL however I couldn't find any appropriate solution.

Comment: I don't exactly know how you want to use the data, but one way that usually works reasonable well is to create a raster mask of your KMZ, and then just read out the pixels where the mask is true. Happy to give you more help if you clarify how you will use the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you clearly, you want to clip an area of interest (ROI) on the raster dataset that you have. If that is so , then i suggest that you first convert the KMZ file you have into a shapefile in ArcMap. Then you can go to the raster processing toobox where you can clip your shapefile to the desired area of interest...